# How to configure vim for embedded programming?

Tags: c, vim, embedded, atmelstudio

I was wondering how to configure vim for embedded programming? Precisely, how to "replace" `Atmel studio` with `vim` (I do not want to install `Atmel studio` with `wine`)?

Imagine we have only a single `main.c` file, `ALE` says that these files cannot be found:

```c
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main() {
    // nothing special
}
```

And of course it does not compile as compiler can't find those header files.

I think I installed all the necessary libraries. Maybe there is some problem with the path? How do I configure the path?

Comment: Install Eclipse with ARV plugin. But actually better do not start with AVR 8 bit uCs. Move straight to the 32bits ARMs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to compile `main.c` with `gcc`, but then I compiled it with `avr-gcc` instead. Warnings of "file not found" didn't go away, but it compiled successfully.

Comment: If You will not provide the full command, which You use to compile the project, I may only suppose that You forget about `-I<path_to_include_directories>` flag. That is why such an error occurs.

Comment: There is no "project", just a single `main.c` file as I stated in the question, and I compiled it with `avr-gcc main.c`.

Comment: Project = source files (e.g. main.c). So write me down full command, which You use.

Comment: You clearly are not paying attention, the **full** command I use is `avr-gcc main.c`.

Comment: "I was trying to compile `main.c` with `gcc`..." - it doesn't mean that full command is `gcc main.c` or `avr-gcc main.c`. For example it could be `avr-gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror main.c -o main.bin` or something more complex... Anyway, as I see, try to specify `I<path_to_header_files_for_avr>`. Try to find, where they are placed and then add the mentioned option to build process.

Comment: Everything works just fine even without the flag for header files. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `Vim` can replace any IDE regardless of type of programming, it doesn't matter whether it is embedded for AVR, embedded for ARM, C/C++, python, Java...

`Vim` is just a powerful text editor, so it is not its problem that You cannot compile your project for AVR. It is not the case of `Vim`. What kind of build system do You use? Is it `Make` or something else? Or maybe You don't use any of these and You compile straight from command line?

Provide us with more information :)

Comment: No. I do not have makefile, And yes, I compile from terminal.